# Autodesk.Viewing.webVR can't load

Tags: forge, autodesk-forge

The webVR extension can't be load.

Code:

```
var options = {
                "docid" : docs[0].path , 
                env : 'Development',
                extensions:[
                    'Autodesk.Viewing.webVR',
                ]
            };
            var viewercon = document.getElementById('viewercon');
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewercon, {}});
            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options,function(){
                    viewer.initialize () ;
                    viewer.loadModel (options.docid) ;
            });
```

viewer3D.js version 2.12

Comment: The "extensions" array has to be passed to the GuiViewer3D constructor, not the Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer. However I think you can only load this extension on deviced that actually support VR and in that case it will be loaded by default.

Comment: thank you for you answer! I fix the code follow,but also can't load the webVR extension.  code: viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewercon, {extensions:['Autodesk.Viewing.VR']});
   Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options,function(){
        viewer.initialize () ;
     avp.logger.setLevel(avp.LogLevels.LOG); 
        viewer.loadModel (options.docid) ;
   });   @Philippe Leefsma

Comment: What kind of browser are you working on? What Philippe mentioned importantly is that you should run the app on the devices support VR, for example, Chrome on iPhone or Android Device, or experimental builds of Chromium for Windows, the default Chrome desktop does not support WebVR, check it out at https://webvr.info/.